# trajectory of bullet, when there is a drag force

Tags: graph, ode

i tried to express the trajectory of bullet when there is a drag force.
however, i am not able to express the graph precisely.
how to depict trajectory from ode equation?.

this is my graph. this graph does not plausible. although i struggled setting different sign of vydot value, this is not working correctly.

[image: my graph]

```
from pylab import*
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


g=10
m=1
k=0.01
y=zeros([2])
vy0=0
vydot=200
vx0=0
vxdot=200
y[0]=vy0
y[1]=vydot
x=zeros([2])
x[0]=vx0
x[1]=vxdot

t=linspace(0,1000,5000)

def fy(y,t):
    g0=y[1]
    g1=-k*y[1]
    return array([g0,g1])
def fx(z,t):
    g0=-x[1]
    g1=-k*(x[1])-g
    return array([g0,g1])

ans1=odeint(fy,y,t)
ans2=odeint(fx,x,t)
ydata=(ans1[:,])
xdata=(ans2[:,])
plt.plot(ydata,xdata)
show()"""
```

Comment: "i am not able to do that" is not much of a description of the problem you're having. You'd be more likely to get help if you include what kind of results you are getting vs. what kind of results you think you should be getting. (And a side benefit to putting detailed information together is that you might be able to solve the problem on your own that way.)

Comment: You should use `def fx(x,t):`. And the drag couples x and y components, so they have to be integrated simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In air, as opposed to liquids, the bullet not only displaces the volume along its path, but also increases the impulse of the displaced air molecules proportional to the velocity. Thus the drag force is

```
vn=sqrt(vx²+vy²)
dragx = -k*vn*vx
dragy = -k*vn*vy
```

Thus use

```
def f(z,t):
    x,y,vx,vy = z
    vn = sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)
    return array([vx, vy, -k*vn*vx, -k*vn*vy-g ])
```

---

For a first overview, consider the problem without drag. Then the solution is

```
x(t) = vx*t        = 200m/s*t
y(t) = vy*t-g/2*t² = 200m/s*t - 5m/s²*t²
```

`y(t)=0` is again met for `t=2*vy/g` at the x coordinate `2*vx*vy/g = 8000m`. Maximum height is reached for `t=vy/g` at height `vy²/(2g)=2000m`.